# Multiplos keys/values em um array javascript

Tags: javascript, array, request

em determinada parte do meu codigo eu preciso fazer uma requisição utilizando javascript com varios ids iguais.

O problema é que ele ta sobrescrevendo os ids com o ultimo selecionado.

Meu Html:

```
<button class="btn btn-default border-none" v-on:click="massDelete()" style="width: 100%">
    Apagar
</button>


<td class="text-center">
       <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="pushId(property.id)">
</td>
```

Meu java script;

```
pushId(propertyid)
        {
            this.ids.push({property_id: propertyid});
        },
massDelete()
{
  var obj = {};
  for(let item of this.ids)
            {
                obj = {property_id: item.property_id};
            }
            console.log(obj);

        }
    }
```

Eu preciso que a resposta seja

```
array({
"property_id": 3
}
{
"property_id": 4
}
{
"property_id": 5
})
```

PS: Eu não posso usar um form por causa da disposição do layout

Comment: Eu não entendi sua dúvida, poderia explicar melhor qual parte do código você tem dúvida? E o que exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: IDs são únicos

Cada elemento pode ter apenas um ID;
Cada página pode ter apenas um elemento com aquele ID.

Voce devia reformular o seu codigo html de modo a não usar o memso id.

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi alterei a pergunta, ve se da pra compreender agora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um array é [], um objeto é {}. Acredito que o que você quer na verdade, é este formato:

```
[
   {
      "property_id": 3
   },
   {
      "property_id": 4
   },
   {
      "property_id": 5
   }
]
```

Seria isso daqui:

```
pushId(propertyid){
   this.ids.push({property_id: propertyid});
},
massDelete(){
   var objs = [];
   for(let item of this.ids){
      objs.push({property_id: item.property_id});
   }
   console.log(objs);
}
```

Porém se parar para pensar, acredito que o "objs" teria o mesmo valor de this.ids, já deu um console.log(this.ids); dentro da sua função massDelete()?

Comment: Eu passo outro parametro no massDelete(Parametro) Quando o cara clica no botao, mas isso ai me ajudou, valeu!